# Swift crash for Release Build when accessing NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm attempting to get/store `[String:Int]` information in `NSUserDefaults`.  Works fine *unless* I build with release.  Then I get a crash on `isEqual:`.  Code is pretty vanilla here:

```
private func storeVersion(storeName: String) -> UInt64 {
  let settings = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
  let versions: [String:Int]
  if let dict = settings.dictionaryForKey(storeVersionKey) as? [String:Int] {
    versions = dict
  } else {
    versions = [ storeName : 0 ]
    settings.setObject(versions, forKey: storeVersionKey)
    settings.synchronize()
  }

  if let version = versions[storeName] {
    return UInt64(version)
  }

  return 0
}

private func setStoreVerion(storeName: String, version: UInt64) {
  let settings = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
  var versions: [String:Int]
  if let dict = settings.dictionaryForKey(storeVersionKey) as? [String:Int] {
    versions = dict
  } else {
    versions = [:]
  }
  versions[storeName] = Int(version)
  settings.setObject(versions, forKey: storeVersionKey)
  settings.synchronize()
}
```

Everything I've read says this should work fine.  However, I'm getting the following crash only in release versions:

```
0
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000027f5beb8
 raw
0
libobjc.A.dylib 
objc_msgSend + 16
isEqual:
1
CoreFoundation  
CFEqual + 452
2
CoreFoundation  
-[CFPrefsPlistSource alreadylocked_setValue:forKey:] + 192
3
CoreFoundation  
-[CFPrefsSource setValue:forKey:] + 76
4
CoreFoundation  
+[CFPrefsSource withSourceForIdentifier:user:byHost:container:perform:] + 860
5
CoreFoundation  
_CFPreferencesSetValueWithContainer + 248
6
Foundation  
-[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) setObject:forKey:] + 56
7
PersistenceLayer    
_TF16PersistenceLayer11UpdateStoreFTSS9toVersionVSs6UInt64_T_ + 2264
```

Line 7 is referring to this code:

```
public func UpdateStore(storeName: String, toVersion version: UInt64) {
  if storeVersion(storeName) >= version {
    return
  }
  DeleteStoreNamed(storeName)
  setStoreVerion(storeName, version)
}
```

Few things to note:

- I only copied part of the stack trace (the rest are startup routines)
- Line 7 is calling to both `storeVersion` (first checking the version) and then conditionally updating that version.  The crash occurs when updating.
- The `DeleteStoreNamed(_)` simply deletes two db files using NSFileManager.  Nothing more.
- This is on the main thread
- This code is contained in an embedded framework (module).
- This is currently Swift 1.2 (haven't migrated to 2.0 yet)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue was my usage of `[String:Int]`.  This worked fine until I tried using a `Release` build configuration.  Something about the optimization process was not converting the type into something that objective-c could use.  By explicitly changing the type to `NSDictionary` before I submitted the object to `NSUserDefaults`, the crash went away.  Guess the compiler needed to be explicitly told what to do.